# Range Slider - how to style on IE/Edge?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to style this range slider on IE. It's been quite a nightmare. Anyone knows why fill color for the track doesn't work?
It's also not quite applying border-radius on the track.

```
   &::-ms-track {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        width: 12.5em;
        height: 8px;
        background: $beige-yellow;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }

    &::-ms-fill-lower {
        height: 8px;
        background: $army-green;
    }

    &::-ms-fill-upper {
        background: $beige-yellow;
    }
```

See full code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMQKdp

Answer (score 1):

First, we should use `input[type="range"]` before the IE proprietary pseudo-elements to style the range slider in IE and Edge. So we should delete the `.slider::-ms-track`, `.slider::-ms-fill-lower`, `.slider::-ms-thumb`, `.slider::-ms-tooltip` part in CSS and write like below instead:

```
    input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
        ...
    }
    input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
        ...
    }
    input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
        ...
    }
    input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
        ...
    }
    input[type="range"]::-ms-tooltip {
        ...
    }
```

Second, the `=>` [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) in JavaScript is not supported in IE. You could use the [Babel's translation](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA-gJRgXhgExMArgWwKZhQB0AjlngE4CeAyngDZ7BQgUAUA5ANpRUAOeZBQCGYAOZ4AuhwCUAbgBQMZSuWIi0Kow14oABQogBFXpwC0ZgG7D6HADQwA1Ouv1y8papXrN2iLoMjSlMOCxxhAA97J3VwiI8vbwQNXj8Aw2MQsIBLMGjnZJxcj09EjGx8QiJy3AIoAFFGSuJgemEICAAZbOgiYTQ0TgArCFlFUq91frR6yzru6AJKTly-LChovBQAPhgAbwnEtWTfPB19DOCqcysbfJcbd0UjmABfBwAzG395IA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=) to make it compatible with IE.

So the final code is like this:

```js
var _R = document.querySelector('[type=range]');

_R.style.setProperty('--val', +_R.value);

_R.style.setProperty('--max', +_R.max);

_R.style.setProperty('--min', +_R.min);

document.documentElement.classList.add('js');

_R.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  _R.style.setProperty('--val', +_R.value);
}, false);
```

```css
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--val) - var(--min))/var(--range));
  --sx: calc(.5*1.5em + var(--ratio)*(100% - 1.5em));
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: transparent;
  font: 1em/1 arial, sans-serif;
  border: none;
}

.slider,
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  width: 12.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  background: #ccc;
}

.js .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#7b1c1a, #7b1c1a) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat #ccc;
}

.slider::-moz-range-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  height: 0.5em;
  background: #ccc;
}

.slider::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 0.5em;
  background: #7b1c1a;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-top: -0.550em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #7b1c1a;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #7b1c1a;
}

#tickmarks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#tickmarks p {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: green;
  color: green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 54px;
  top: -34px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #7b1c1a;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  height: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #7b1c1a;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="5" max="20" value="10" step='2.5' class="slider" id="myRange" list='tickmarks'>
  <div id="tickmarks">
    <p>5</p>
    <p>7.5</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>12.5</p>
    <p>15</p>
    <p>17.5</p>
    <p>20</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Besides, here's a very useful [article](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-range-slider-style/) about styling range slider across multiple browsers, you could also check it.